# htaccess - block traffic WITH specific get request

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm being hit with a get request up to 20 times a second. This is a wordpress site, here is an attached apache log

`108.162.216.170 - - [24/Jun/2014:16:42:26 -0700] "GET /?edd_action=check_license&license=506e284d78dyd7dyd5d4d3f07d&item_name=FILE+Name HTTP/1.1" 200 526 "-" "WordPress/3.9.1; http://soomaalidamaanta.net"`

Here is my htaccess, but I'm not having luck blocking it.

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} soomaalidamaanta\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} soomaalidamaanta\.net
RewriteRule .* - [F]

order allow,deny
deny from 68.171.211.157
allow from all

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /?edd_action=check_license&license=506e284d78dyd7dyd5d4d3f07d&item_name=FILE+Name [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]`
```

Answer (score 2):

Tweak your 2nd block rule's regex like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} edd_action=check_license&license=506e284d78dyd7dyd5d4d3f07d&item_name=FILE [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: This won't work. I need to target that specific licence number only actually. It's the one they are hitting. I want others to get by without a problem.

Comment: Alright check updated rule to target specific license `506e284d78dyd7dyd5d4d3f07d`

Comment: OK, your code works when I do the querystring test=true but not their actual request. I'll have to figure out why.

Comment: If you tell me what exact URI yo are getting in actual request I can probably suggest something.

Comment: I got it working by targeting the user agent. Your help was great.

Comment: `HTTP_USER_AGENT` represents client's browser. That cannot be `soomaalidamaanta` unless it is customized by a client.

Comment: It's another web servers Wordpress installation contacting mine. Their web server useragent is listed in the original post `WordPress/3.9.1; http://soomaalidamaanta.net` so that's how I was able to block them. No matter what I tried, your rule wouldn't block the query. I'm not saying your code is wrong, but probably something I was doing wrong.

Comment: But the thing is they can change `HTTP_USER_AGENT` anytime they want and then your block rule won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I'd change the first rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} soomaalidamaanta [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

and drop the second rule.

- Since `soomaalidamaanta` is in the request, it looks to me like you don't need the second rule.
- No need to check for `.net` or `.com`, the one conditions finds it either way
- In the rule, `^` is enough, no need for the `.*`

Comment: They are still hitting just as frequently.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding out how to block by user agent, and since this user agent specified the site in question, I blocked it and it's working now.

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Chrome [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} soomaalidamaanta [NC] 
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```